# display the most recent file in a directory using linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I need to display the content of the recent file in a directory, for my example it's a log file that gets generated for each execution hence I need to display the newest one
the command :

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1
```

output the right name, meaning the most recent file in a directory, my goal is to output the content of this file by further piping 
How could we do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat `ls -Art | tail -n1`
```

or,

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1 | xargs cat
```